# Chrome Ext. OAuth 2.0 with Youtube API v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I'm building a Chrome Extension with Youtube API access. But I don't get an authentification against Youtube. It looks like there is no up-to-date source or sample. The [Tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) here uses some chrome-oauth lib from 2010, the other [Source](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Samples) here uses a different lib, I guess its useful for browser based Auth & API access.
I have a Dev Key, a client id for installed apps (type: Chrome), YT API Key (Simple API Access).

My Chrome App uses following manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Youtube Chrome Ext",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Youtube Chrome Ext",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "main.html",
            "container":"tab"
        }
    },

    "options_page": "settings.html",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://gdata.youtube.com/",
        "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken",
        "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
        "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
    ]
}
```

with following backgroundHandler.js file for authentification with Youtube over oAuth2.0:

```
(function(global){

    global.backgroundHandler = {

        initBackground : function(){
            var self = this;
            var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
                'request_url'     : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
                'authorize_url'   : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
                'access_url'      : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
                'consumer_key'    : 'anonymous',
                'consumer_secret' : 'anonymous',
                'scope'           : 'http://gdata.youtube.com',
                'app_name'        : 'YouTube Ext'
            });

            oauth.authorize(this.onAuthorized());
        },

        onAuthorized : function() {
            //I'm not authorized - no window with grant access was displayed ...
        }

    };
})(window);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    backgroundHandler.initBackground();
});
```

Note Youtube don't uses consumer key & secret.

background.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/oAuth/chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/oAuth/chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handler/backgroundHandler.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My biggest problem is to get somehow the OAuth done and do authentificated requests against Youtube. It looks like for me, that there exists no source on the whole www which is up-to-date.

I would be glad if someone could help me.

BR,
mybecks

Comment: Are you running into any errors? I eyeballed the code and see some mixing of v2 and v3 going on. I would recommend first getting a non CWS sample going first so you have your keys and scopes in order, then looking at CWS. We have a JS sample somewhere that is pending publish to the documentation site, but it isn't a Chrome app sample.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experiment and I tested this library:

https://github.com/borismus/oauth2-extensions

I followed the steps indicated by the author and I changed the popup.html and popup.js files, trying show the YouTube video recommendations for the current user

popup.html:

```
<head>
  <title>YouTube Recommendations</title>
  <script src="oauth2/oauth2.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <style>
    #success { display: none; }
  </style>
</head>

<div id="loading">
Loading...
</div>
<div id="success">
  <ul id="activities"></ul>
</div>
```

popup.js:

```
var google = new OAuth2('google', {
  client_id: '{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}',
  client_secret: '{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET}',
  api_scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
});

google.authorize(function() {

  var YOUTUBE_ACTIVITIES_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&home=true&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyCx1xab1VHU7NdT6d2_x8i3p9RIZrtgR8k';

  var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
  var success = document.getElementById('success');
  var activities = document.getElementById('activities');

  // Make an XHR that retrieve activities with YouTube Data API
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if(xhr.status == 200) {
        // Great success: parse response with JSON
        var activitiesResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var items = activitiesResponse.items;
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          // Iterates over activities
          var activity = items[i];
          if ((activity.snippet.type == 'recommendation')&&(activity.contentDetails.recommendation.resourceId.videoId)){
            activities.innerHTML += '<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + activity.contentDetails.recommendation.resourceId.videoId + '" target="_blank">' + activity.snippet.title + '</a></li>';
          }
        }

        loading.style.display = 'none';
        success.style.display = 'block';

      } else {
          // Request failure: something bad happened
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', YOUTUBE_ACTIVITIES_URL, true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + google.getAccessToken());

  xhr.send();

});
```